# Silverlight 3D XNA Error - The type or namespace does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, 3d, xna

I'm trying to follow some tutorials for building a Silverlight 3D XNA project.

I'm able to display the 3D surface but once I start using `Vector3` or `VertexPositionNormalTexture` (or using any of the XNA helper entities) I get that the type or namespce does not exist.

I've got these includes:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
```

I've includeed the References in the Silverlight Project, namely:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Extensions
System.Windows.Xna
```

and a bunch of others I'm not sure are relevant. These were under the .NET tab, perhaps I need to get them elsewhere, and these aren't for Silverlight? I'm not sure.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, Silverlight 5 and XNA 4

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get XNA working in Silverlight in separate projects, I am pretty confident I missed something. Just double-check everything is included.